# Why do i get an error when i try to table a vector in r?

Tags: r

```
v <- c(1,2,3,3,4)
table(v)
```

I get this error:Error in table(v) : unused argument (v).
Can someone explain this?

Comment: Runs fine for me, do you perhaps have a package loaded with another function called `table`?

Comment: @JonSpring Im not too sure i loaded the rvest, dplyr, and tidyverse package. How do I call the table function that is from the base package?

Comment: `base::table(v)` should do it too.